# Converting a string data held in a variable to URI to show in browser

Tags: android, string, uri

Following is a snippet from my code

```
Uri uriUrl =  Uri.parse(web);
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

The variable `String web="http://google.com"`
Upon parsing and launching the web browser the address shown in the address bar of the browser is http://%20google.com
the page doesnt open due to the "%20".
how to get over this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the string variable is not "http://google.com" but "http:// google.com", i.e. there is an extra space character right after "http://". Just remove that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the String as:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
```

and now check it.